# Conditional if sum

Tags: conditional-statements, cplex

I want to sum over a range (Areas) except if j is not equal to k.
Can anybody help me?

I tried:

```
forall( k in Areas ) 
        sum ( j in Areas: j!=k ) X[k][j] == 1;
Also tried:
forall( k in Areas ) 
        sum ( j in Areas) (j!=k)*X[k][j] == 1;

    int NbAreas = 5;

    range Areas = 1..NbAreas;

    float P[Areas] = [0, 0.3, 0.65, 0.2, 0.1];
    float D[Areas] = [0, 7, 5, 3, 9];
    float FROMTO[Areas][Areas] =    [ 
                                    [0, 2, 5, 1, 3],
                                    [2, 0, 4, 3, 8],
                                    [5, 4, 0, 6, 2],
                                    [1, 3, 6, 0, 7],
                                    [3, 8, 2, 7, 0]];


    dvar int Y[Areas];
    dvar int T[Areas];
    dvar int X[Areas][Areas] in 0..1;


    maximize sum( i in Areas ) P[i] * Y[i];
    subject to {
        forall( k in Areas ) 
            sum ( j in Areas: j!=k) X[k][j] == 1;
        forall( k in Areas)
            sum ( i in Areas: i!=k) X[i][k] == 1;
        forall( i in Areas) forall (j in Areas) T[i] + FROMTO[i][j] -     T[j] - 100*(1-X[i][j]) <= 0;
        T[1] == 0;
        forall( i in Areas: i!=1) T[i] - D[i] - 1000*(1-Y[i]) <= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I take it you meant

> I want to sum over a range (Areas) except if j is **equal** (instead
>   of "not equal") to k.

I also assume that your issue is that the model you posted is infeasible. You should label your constraints so that the conflict refiner can run and then look at the results of the conflict refiner. If I label your constraints like so:

```
maximize sum( i in Areas ) P[i] * Y[i];
subject to {
    forall( k in Areas ) 
        sum1: sum ( j in Areas: j!=k) X[k][j] == 1;
    forall( k in Areas)
        sum2: sum ( i in Areas: i!=k) X[i][k] == 1;
    forall( i in Areas) forall (j in Areas)
        fromto: T[i] + FROMTO[i][j] - T[j] - 100*(1-X[i][j]) <= 0;
    T[1] == 0;
    forall( i in Areas: i!=1)
        limit: T[i] - D[i] - 1000*(1-Y[i]) <= 0;
```

Then I get this conflict:

```
 sum1(1):      X(1)(2) + X(1)(3) + X(1)(4) + X(1)(5)  = 1
 sum1(2):      X(2)(1) + X(2)(3) + X(2)(4) + X(2)(5)  = 1
 sum1(3):      X(3)(1) + X(3)(2) + X(3)(4) + X(3)(5)  = 1
 sum1(4):      X(4)(1) + X(4)(2) + X(4)(3) + X(4)(5)  = 1
 sum1(5):      X(5)(1) + X(5)(2) + X(5)(3) + X(5)(4)  = 1
 fromto(1)(2): 100 X(1)(2) + T(1) - T(2) <= 98
 fromto(1)(3): 100 X(1)(3) + T(1) - T(3) <= 95
 fromto(1)(4): 100 X(1)(4) + T(1) - T(4) <= 99
 fromto(1)(5): 100 X(1)(5) + T(1) - T(5) <= 97
 fromto(2)(1): 100 X(2)(1) - T(1) + T(2) <= 98
 fromto(2)(3): 100 X(2)(3) + T(2) - T(3) <= 96
 fromto(2)(4): 100 X(2)(4) + T(2) - T(4) <= 97
 fromto(2)(5): 100 X(2)(5) + T(2) - T(5) <= 92
 fromto(3)(1): 100 X(3)(1) - T(1) + T(3) <= 95
 fromto(3)(2): 100 X(3)(2) - T(2) + T(3) <= 96
 fromto(3)(4): 100 X(3)(4) + T(3) - T(4) <= 94
 fromto(3)(5): 100 X(3)(5) + T(3) - T(5) <= 98
 fromto(4)(1): 100 X(4)(1) - T(1) + T(4) <= 99
 fromto(4)(2): 100 X(4)(2) - T(2) + T(4) <= 97
 fromto(4)(3): 100 X(4)(3) - T(3) + T(4) <= 94
 fromto(4)(5): 100 X(4)(5) + T(4) - T(5) <= 93
 fromto(5)(1): 100 X(5)(1) - T(1) + T(5) <= 97
 fromto(5)(2): 100 X(5)(2) - T(2) + T(5) <= 92
 fromto(5)(3): 100 X(5)(3) - T(3) + T(5) <= 98
 fromto(5)(4): 100 X(5)(4) - T(4) + T(5) <= 93
```

So it seems your data in `FROMTO` and `T` does not allow a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "except if j is not equal to k".

So instead of

```
forall( k in Areas)
        sum ( i in Areas: i!=k) X[i][k] == 1;
```

I would write

```
forall( k in Areas)
        sum ( i in Areas: i==k) X[i][k] == 1;
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for your help! However, this makes X[i][k] 1 only if i=k, while this is not allowed.

Kind regards

Comment: So when you wrote 
"except if j is not equal to k" you mean "except if j is equal to k" ?